# Call a form by a script that is called by a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that calls a dropdown with some options and I'm trying to make that, if one is select, call a form. I already did that but the option was out of the script. Then I did this code but doesn't work.

This is my html code:

```
<form class="formcriacao" action="inqueritos.php" method="post">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="submit" class="btn" id="btvoltar" value="Voltar"><br><br>
    <p class="txt1">Clique no botão a baixo para adicionar as perguntas pretendidas para o novo inquerito.</p>
    <input type="button" method="post"class="btnadd" id="addperguntas"value="Adicionar Perguntas">
</form>
```

My javascript code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 30;
    var wrapper         = $(".formcriacao");
    var add_button      = $(".btnadd");

    var x = 0;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div>\
            <br><input class="txtpergunta" maxlength="100" type="text" name="mytext[]"/>&nbsp&nbsp\<input type="submit" class="removepergunta" value="Remover"><br><br>\
            <div class="dropdown">\
            <p class="txttipopergunta">Tipo de Resposta: <select name="dropdown" size=1></p>\
            <option value="1">Resposta de Texto</option>\
            <option value="2">Resposta Multipla</option>\
            </select>\
            </div>');
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".removepergunta", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
<script>
$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){

  if ($(this).val() == "2"){
    $(dropdown).append('<div>\
    <form>\
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> <br>\
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> <br>\
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> \
</form>')
   }
});​
 </script>
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: $(dropdown).append(), what is the dropdown variable here

Comment: The $(dropdown).append() check the class dropdown above.

Comment: Then you need the trigger the `submit` event on `change` event of `select[name=dropdown]` and then it will work.

Comment: your code have a lot bugs and the intention of writing this code is not clear at all.

Comment: The code can be a little confusing because you still learn how to program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the snippet,  $(dropdown).append(), this was a wrong move, check the code, i hope it does what you meant. :D

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 30;
    var wrapper         = jQuery(".formcriacao");
    var add_button      = jQuery(".btnadd");

    var x = 0;
    jQuery(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            jQuery(wrapper).append('<div>\
            <br><input class="txtpergunta" maxlength="100" type="text" name="mytext[]"/>&nbsp&nbsp\<input type="submit" class="removepergunta" value="Remover"><br><br>\
            <div class="dropdown">\
            <p class="txttipopergunta">Tipo de Resposta: <select name="dropdown" size=1></p>\
            <option value="1">Resposta de Texto</option>\
            <option value="2">Resposta Multipla</option>\
            </select>\
            </div>');
        }
    });
    jQuery(wrapper).on("click",".removepergunta", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); jQuery(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

jQuery('body').on('change', 'select[name=dropdown]',function(){

  if (jQuery(this).val() == "2"){
    jQuery(jQuery('.dropdown')).append('<div>\
    <form>\
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male <br>\
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female <br>\
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other \
</form>')
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="formcriacao" action="inqueritos.php" method="post">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="submit" class="btn" id="btvoltar" value="Voltar"><br><br>
    <p class="txt1">Clique no botão a baixo para adicionar as perguntas pretendidas para o novo inquerito.</p>
    <input type="button" method="post"class="btnadd" id="addperguntas"value="Adicionar Perguntas">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help now I have to see a way so that it does not change in all the questions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
$('#show').on('click', function () {
    $('.center').show();
    $(this).hide();
})

$('#close').on('click', function () {
    $('.center').hide();
    $('#show').show();
})
```

```css
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 20px;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); 
}

.hideform {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center hideform">
    <button id="close" style="float: right;">X</button>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="firstname">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="lastname">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<button id="show">Call the form</button>
```

Comment: the frist edit by Akhil Aravind work but thanks btw. I'm creating a code that auto increment id to each div that is creat by the btnadd button.